# How to get alerts in arrays with loops and previous values of boxes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a problem with creating an alert in loop of boxes.

```
//Box process
if (barstate.isconfirmed)
    //boxup
    if (array.size(boxup) > 0)
        for i = array.size(boxup) - 1 to 0
            tbox1 = array.get(boxup, i)
            bottom = box.get_bottom(tbox1)
            topprice = box.get_top(tbox1)
            if (low < bottom and low != bottom)
                array.remove(boxup, i)
                box.delete(tbox1)
            if topprice[0]<topprice[1] and bottom[0]>bottom[1]
                alert("get ready",freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
            continue
```

My main thing is to get prices of previous box top and bottom and compare it with actual top and bottom of  box to get alert.

These values

```
bottom = box.get_bottom(tbox1)
topprice = box.get_top(tbox1)
```

In this function

```
if topprice[0]<topprice[1] and bottom[0]>bottom[1]
```

It doesnt work and I dont know how to make it send alerts if conditions are true. Any suggestions will be welcomed. Thanks